# How to see the original code assigned to a value, such as [x <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, color=dose))]

Tags: r

Forgive the mistakes with proper terminology. I'm trying to self-teach R from a non-computer science background.

I know that I can assign a variable some lines of code, but I want to identify what I originally assigned to the variable. For example,
    `x <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, color=dose))`

Then, I want to do something so that the output shows me the code assigned to x. For example,
    `ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, color=dose)`

I tried just clicking on the variable in the RStudio "environment" pane, and it shows me some info but I really just want the code itself so I can use it in another context. I'm a dummy for not saving what I originally wrote down.

Comment: RStudio also has a history pane. Although some functions, e.g. `lm`, store the creating call in the resulting object, I'm unaware of any way getting the original calls from most functions (including `ggplot`).

Comment: @Axeman THANK YOU! That totally works

Comment: One other exception I can think of is that when you create a function, R usually keeps a record of the original source code.

Comment: Many regression functions save their calling code in an argument named `call` but ggplot2 functions are not of that sort. Look at `x <- lm(len ~ dose,ToothGrowth);
 x$call`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can't get a 'call' from ggplot, like the others said, BUT you can get all the data and info required to create the plot.
Foe example:

x$data - shows data used for plotting,

x$mapping - shows how variables were used on the plot

Try exploring the 'x' object and you will probably get all you need (and maybe even more).